# Python doesn't see module that it surely has in its path

Tags: python, python-module

My install env is Windows. My python doesn't see modules it has in its site-package dir, i.e.:

```
C:\Dane\Python>pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Dane\Python\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

But:

```
C:\Dane\Python>python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
['C:\\Dane\\Python', 'C:\\Dane\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
```

And:

```
C:\Dane\Python>dir c:\dane\python\lib\site-packages
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is C60F-8FD5

 Directory of c:\dane\python\lib\site-packages

2018-07-10  09:30    <DIR>          .
2018-07-10  09:30    <DIR>          ..
2018-07-10  09:50               126 easy_install.py
2018-07-10  09:30    <DIR>          pip
2018-07-10  09:50    <DIR>          pip-10.0.1.dist-info
2018-07-10  09:14    <DIR>          pkg_resources
2018-07-10  09:14    <DIR>          setuptools
2018-07-10  09:50    <DIR>          setuptools-40.0.0.dist-info
2018-07-10  09:14    <DIR>          wheel
2018-07-10  09:50    <DIR>          wheel-0.31.1.dist-info
2018-07-10  09:14    <DIR>          __pycache__
```

It complains the same about wheel, setuptools etc.

Is there anything I could do to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure your python packages are in env path?

Comment: Isn't that what output of "python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"" says? And yes - they're in %PATH&

Comment: which version of Python you are using?

Comment: 3.7.0..........

Comment: But the directories you mentioned here are of Python2 right?

Comment: All directories I mentioned/showed are from python 3.7.0 Windows 32-bit distribution unpacked from zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade  pip
```

or maybe

```
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade  pip
```

or try

1. Download this file: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
2. Execute: `python3 get-pip.py` (you need to open a shell in the correct folder)

If any of these commands works, please tell me which one, I will edit my post

Comment: "no module named pip"

Comment: I've done get-pip, that's why it's site-packages already (see my post)

Comment: You have shown the Python 2 directory, not python 3

Comment: This directory was created by extracting contents of python-3.7.0-embed-win32.zip downloaded from python webpage.

Comment: Just delete everything and install https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows

If you don't know exactely what you do, it will a lot easier.

Comment: Installing anything is not an option. I need "portable" Python that works WITHOUT installation.